# Show that this antiderivative result holds if you use Maclaurin series representations in place of functions

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

We know from integral calculus that by using the substitution method:
$$
\int 2xe^{x^2} = e^{x^2} +C
$$

Show that this antiderivative result is true if you use Maclaurin series representations in place of the functions. 
$$
\int 2xe^{x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {2x^{2n+2}\over n!(2n+2)}
$$
I'm able to find the Maclaurin series representation but I'm not sure how to modify them to show they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x^2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=e^{x^2}-1$.  Add a constant of integration to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

We compute
\begin{align}
\int 2xe^{x^2}\ \mathsf dx &= \int \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2x^{2n+1}}{n!}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac2{n!}\int x^{2n+1}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0} \frac{2x^{2n+2}}{n!(2n+2)},
\end{align}
where the interchange of integral and summation is justified by the uniform convergence of the power series.
Dividing by the common factor of $2$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{(n+1)!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = e^{x^2} - 1,
$$
which is equal to $e^{x^2}$ up to the constant of integration.